# Thunderbird 15.0 and Gmail Not Syncing Correctly

Tags: thunderbird, gmail, imap

Just got done reading these articles:

https://support.mozillamessaging.com/en-US/kb/thunderbird-and-gmail#w_configuring-your-gmail-account

http://lifehacker.com/314574/turn-thunderbird-into-the-ultimate-gmail-imap-client

These basically are good ways to configure Thunderbird as far as I can tell.  In fact, it is exactly how I did configure my recent Thunderbird setup.

But I must still be missing something or not understanding how IMAP works, because low and behold, there I was, going through the instructions in the first link above, and a message or two came in to my inbox and they did not go to their corresponding Gmail labels.

Can anyone explain this to me?  How to I confirm that they always go to the labels?  Of course, I can drag and drop these messages and get them to where they need to be but that doesn't seem like a good way to work around this.  I've also considered message filters but the above articles make it seem that these aren't needed.

In the past, when I've used Outlook 2010, I have also, in addition to labels, used "rules" and this works OK, but it'd be nice to have this system work as it should.

Any help is appreciated.

**Edit**

Although I still haven't totally figured out how the labels work exactly, I did discover (or maybe re-discover) that the default Gmail label is "Inbox".  So if you set a label like "_work" then the message will have "Inbox" and "_work" as a label.  Although, it is still unknown why a message from the exact same sender would yield one message with only the "_work" label and one message with both the "Inbox" and the "_work" label, at least now I can manually label and un-label messages and have this propagate through to Thunderbird.

I guess I'm just not getting it.  I wish this made more sense to me...

What sucks is that apparently at least one person here thinks I'm not doing my due diligence and is down-voting me without explaining.  I mean, geez, if you down-vote someone on these boards, you ought to at least give an explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a misunderstanding about labels in Gmail.  What I am truly looking for is basically what email clients call rules or filters, but in Gmail, and for these to propagate to the email client.  I don't think it works that way, so I might be out of luck.  But for the time being, here is what I've done:

Set up filters in Thunderbird, such that the mail goes here and there and then Gmail handle the archiving.  This way the server stays put and my client is organized the way I want it.